# AttributeError: 'TFBertModel' object has no attribute 'parameters'

Tags: python, nlp, attributeerror, bert-language-model, transformer-model

Hello I am trying to train a Bert Model for a tokenizer I had trained. I imported

```
from transformers import TFBertModel

model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

Now I am trying to initialise the training by defining the Optimizer like this

```
from transformers import AdamW

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
```

However I am getting the following error

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 from transformers import AdamW
2
----> 3 optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

AttributeError: 'TFBertModel' object has no attribute 'parameters'

Following a tutorial on Youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04oZ2P0uvp0&t=1501s&ab_channel=code_your_own_AI

Answer (score 0):

`AdamW` only works with PyTorch models. The TF equivalent is [AdamWeightDecay](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/optimizer_schedules#transformers.AdamWeightDecay)

```
from transformers import AdamWeightDecay

optimizer = AdamWeightDecay(lr=5e-5)
```